# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/X.framework/X

Tags: ios, xcode, xcframework

When I try to run app on real device,I face this issue.I tried these solutions but they don't work

- I cleaned derived data and delete the app
- I changed frameworks, libraries , embedded content to "embed & sign"
- Rechecking if  X.XCFramework is in "Link binaries with libraries " at Build Phase or
  not.but it was there
- Copy framework in copy bundle resources
- I changed installation directory to @executable_path/Frameworks in framework build setting
  I set Framework search paths and Library search path to physical framework path in host application
  The Xcode version is 13.0

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/X.framework/X
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/D3E0B89E-B0B2-4511-9B33-84EA9AF51821/Y.app/Y
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D3E0B89E-B0B2-4511-9B33-84EA9AF51821/Y.app/Frameworks/X.framework/X: missing LC_DYLD_INFO load command